# Global variables don't mantain their status after the usage of two distinct functions

Tags: python, compiler-construction, global-variables, yacc

So I'm having trouble for days now. Basically, I'm making a compiler for a language i am creating using python. We got the sintax and lexic part down, now the directory procedure and the variable table (symbol table) is being created. In my Yacc file I have:

**Yacc.py**

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
import sys

tokens = Lex.tokens
#Global variables
procs = { }
current_fid = ""

# add new value to the procedure directory
def add_procs_to_dict(fid, ftipo, fparams, fdict):
    proc_dict = {}
    proc_dict[fid] = {
        'Tipo' : ftipo,
        'Params' : fparams,
        'Var_dict' : fdict
    }
    return proc_dict

# add new variable value to the procedure directory
def add_vars_to_dict(vid, vtipo, vparams):
    var_dict = {
        'Nombre' : vid,
        'Tipo' : vtipo,
        'Params' : vparams
        }
    print(current_fid)
    print(procs)    
    return proc_dict


# Parsing Rules    
def p_juego(p):
    '''Juego : JUEGO ID DOSP JuegoA JuegoB MainProgram'''
    current_fid = p[2]
    procs = add_procs_to_dict( p[2], p[1], 'void', {})

def p_vars(p):
    '''Vars : VAR ID COR_I Exp COR_D VarSizeA Vars2 DOSP Tipo PCOMA'''
    add_vars_to_dict( p[2], p[9], p[4])
```

The important thing to note here is that i'm creating a a variable that saves the current ID (named `current_fid` which is the name of the last procedure being inserted in the dictionary) and a dictionary variable (named `procs` which is the procedure/function directory) as a global scope.

When the parser enters the parsing rule `p_juego(p):` (given that the code its being fed is correct, and it is I already run it alone) it suppose to set to the variables (`current_fid` and `procs`) the value it found on the parser process. It does set the values alright. I could print the variables inside the function and returns the expected values.

Once once the parser exits the function `p_juego(p)` and enters another function like `p_vars(p)` (this function writes on the dictionary the symbol table for the last procedure/function inserted on the global directory) the global variables (`current_fid` and `procs`) have no value inside them. There is 2 prints inside the `p_vars(p)` that always displays null for the variables.

I'm relatively new to python and maybe i'm missing something about the language. My intention was if I define a variables before everything (at the top of the code), the functions that uses those "global" variable will update their values and always keep themt even if another function tries to access them.
I tried adding the procedures in a new python file named Semantics.py but the value of the variables is always null outside the function that previously set the value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please include just enough code/information which is needed to showcase and reproduce the actual problem you are having. Try to decouple the nature of the problem from your actual code as much as possible. Read [this](http://www.stackoverflow/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I deleted parts of my code that doesn't belong to the actual problem. The link posted is broken, can you post the link again?

Comment: Where do you run these functions? I think that showing that part of the code can help us for the problem understanding

Comment: This question will be hard to answer for me since I'm using the Ply.yacc library that pretty much does everything for me. The procedures are being called as the correct grammar is being found on the source.txt (that file has my created lenguaje for the compiler). Maybe you are trying to ask if the functions are being called not in the order i expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid scoping problems like this and to be more explicit I suggest you make use of a class. Then you can use self.variable to hold information between class method calls.

Comment: I tried creating an instance of a class that has the procedures that sets the variables. But like thecurrent_fid string variable and the procs dictionary variable, the instance of the class forgets the values that  were set on the functions.

Comment: Then it's import to know the scope in which you run your functions.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]
There are a lot of problem in your code.

First of all:

Your function *add_vars_to_dict*, defines and assign a dict that you will never use (*var_dict*) and tries to return something that doesn't exists in the function scope (*proc_dict*).

Second:

The function *p_juego*, everytime that's called, reassignes the value of the dict, that make you lost the precedent values of *procs*

```
procs = add_procs_to_dict( p[2], p[1], 'void', {})
```

However, as suggested from majodi, in general you can solve global variable issues using a class, in which you use instance variables, instead of the global ones

something like these:

```
class ClassTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.procs = {}
        self.current_fid = ""

    # add new value to the procedure directory
    def add_procs_to_dict(self, fid, ftipo, fparams, fdict):
        # do something

    # add new variable value to the procedure directory
    def add_vars_to_dict(self, vid, vtipo, vparams):
        # do something

    # Parsing Rules
    def p_juego(self, p):
        # do something

    def p_vars(self, p):
        # do something
```

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. The first answer, i am aware the variable _var_dict_ doesn't do anything yet but it will. I left it there but for the sake of the example I changed the content for a _print_ _proc_ because a I wanted to enphasize that that specific "global" variable wasn't getting any content. The second part, that function its suppose to be called once but I think this is a major problem. I think I should fix that part as you said, encapsulating everything within a class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their quick responses. I did made another class as most of you suggested but the reason I was not retaining my global values was because the functions were called on the order i wasn't expecting. The PLY library uses a bottom-up process to navigate the sintax tree. Indeed, the functions were called when the value was being read before even was set.

I appreciate everyone's responses since this was my first post in SO and i'm encouraged by everyone who responded an answer, asked me a question or even corrected my post to keep using the website.

Thanks again.